# Responsive size 767px-768px not showing on ipad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, responsive-design

I am having an issue with the responsive.css/template.css. I am doing the responsive for a website and all the sizes seem to be working fine other than 767px-768px for the iPad. I have made multiple changes like changing widths ect.. and nothing happen. I tried something drastic like background pink and nothing happened.

It seems as though the iPad isn't seeing sizes 768px-767px.

I have both an iPad and Google Chrome's Re-sizer both at the same size but are slightly different.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your CSS media query for the the iPad part?

Answer (score 1):

first of all try resizing your browser window to see if its an ipad problem or this is something related to your media queries. Beyond that, you can check for two meta tags:

1 - Will adjust viewport to display your content into a small screen (and not based on pixels as ipad has a lot of them):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

2 - Will state that your css sheet will be used in all types of media:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
```

If that isnt working at all, check again how you are handling media queries and if the layout isnt breaking apart for smaller sizes, like floats and displays being messed up. Beyond that, you might need specific tags for ipad displaying content (which I dont remember now, but you might find easily).

Hope this helps on troubleshooting the basics.